# search for multiple words using mysql MATCH AGAINST

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this basic mySQL query which works great:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `clients` WHERE 
        MATCH(`LNAME`) AGAINST('$c')  OR
        MATCH(`FNAME`) AGAINST('$c')  OR
        MATCH(`MAIL`) AGAINST('$c')  OR
        MATCH(`TEL`) AGAINST('$c')  "
```

where $c is the search query. Now this works with all single words/numbers but whenever I add 2 words no results are returned.

For example, if my database has `aaaa bbbb` in LNAME and I search for "aaaa bbbb" I get nothing back, however when I search for "aaaa" or "bbbb" it does work. I tried adding IN BOOLEAN MODE but it doesn't make a difference.

Could ayone explain to me how this works? $c is composed of letters, numbers and/or a @

thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you set those fields as FullText index?

Comment: @Ofir Baruch http://tinypic.com/r/30cov9s/5

Comment: Wait a second , if you're about to search in "short" fields , why using fulltext at all? fulltext used to search in TEXT , BLOB fields. Try using `LIKE` - it will give you better results.

Comment: @Ofir Baruch I used $sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ',LNAME, FNAME, TEL, MAIL) LIKE '%". $c ."%'"; and it works :D. Post an answer and i'll give you a credit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First , you should use MATCH AGAINST like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `clients` WHERE MATCH(`LNAME`,`FNAME`,`MAIL`,`TEL`) AGAINST('$c')"
```

Please notice:

> Short words are ignored, the default minimum length is 4 characters.
>   You can change the min and max word length with the variables
>   ft_min_word_len and ft_max_word_len

and:

> If a word is present in more than 50% of the rows it will have a
>   weight of zero. This has advantages on large datasets, but can make
>   testing difficult on small ones.

You can use `LIKE` and it probably will have better results.
Example of usage:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `clients` WHERE `LNAME` LIKE '%$c%' OR `FNAME` LIKE '%$c%' OR ..."
```